# Dynamic Link Error

Tags: c, linker

I am observing some behavior for which I am finding it tough to reason.

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
int timer_temp_var;

if ((timer_temp_var/1000.0) > 5.0) 
{
  //Do something
}
```

This piece leads to link error.

```
> 
> dld: warning: Undefined symbol _d_fle"
> dld: no output written make[1]: ***
> [app.elf] Error 1
```

But on replacing the equality check as :

```
if ((timer_temp_var/1000.0) < 5.0)  // replace '>' with '<'.
```

I see no issues.

Also instead of doing division by 1000.0 if I do by 1000 as follows:

```
 if ((timer_temp_var/1000) > 5) 
    {
      //Do something
    }
```

I see no issues irrespective of the kind of equality check.

The application is compiled to run on a pSOS operating system.

What is the reason for such a behavior?

Comment: have you tried dumping the generated assembly code to see if something weird is hapening?

Comment: What compiler, linker and platform (development and target) are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Seems your compiler replaces ">" operator with call to `_d_fle()` function, so you need to link some library to your executable.

Surprisingly "<" works although it should be replaced with `d_fgt()` function that most likely to be located in the same lib.

Changing from `100.0` to `100` makes left operand of ">" integer and it seems integer comparison doesn't require any function calls - probably it gets compiled to CPU instruction rather than function call.

EDIT: Looks like you need SFPE (software floating-point emulation) library. Do you have anything like libsfpe ?

Answer (score 1):

The change from 1000.0 to 1000 suggest problem with floating point operation. Try cast 1000.0 to (int) and see if you have any progress.

Changing the sign < to >  sounds not reasonable to lead to any changes...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a floating-point library. Try including the math library (libm.a) and see if that does the trick.